# How to create reusable toastService with primeVue toast?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, toast, primevue

I want to know if there's a way to create a reusable scritp/class/service with primevue toast function calls, in such a way that I don't need to call the primevue toast functions directly in every single component.

What I've tried to do up until now, was to create a **ToastService.ts** like this:

```
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast';

    const toast = useToast();

    export function addMsgSuccess(): void {
        toast.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Test', detail: 'Test', life: 3000 });
    }
```

But this code crashes my application and I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: No PrimeVue Toast provided!at useToast
> (usetoast.esm.js?18cb:8:1) eval (ToastService.ts?73ba:3:1)
> Module../src/shared/service/ToastService.ts (app.js:1864:1)
> **webpack_require** (app.js:849:30) fn (app.js:151:20) eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js?!./src/views/cadastro-plano/CadastroPlano.ts?vue&type=script&lang=ts:31:87)
> Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js?!./src/views/cadastro-plano/CadastroPlano.ts?

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, or to create functions that make this add() call, so I don't need to call it everysingle time?

Comment: What happens when you put `const toast = useToast();`inside the function ?

Comment: I get no error, but the toast doest not appear when the function is called

Comment: Actually there is no error, when the component is loaded, but when the function is called, the same error pops out.

Comment: have a look at this : https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/1442

Comment: I already placed ToastService in main.ts and inserted it in app.use() method.
The error persists... :(

Comment: And when you use it normaly in the same project, there is no issue ?

Comment: Exactly. It is working just fine in all components where I use the this.$toast.add()

Comment: Could be that is not finding the <Toast /> element in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution without extra dependencies or importing/exporting App

It is more imports, but this way you can have sensible consistent defaults. In my case exporting anything from main.js is not an option, so without extra dependencies it is my only choice.

**With a class**

In toastNotificationHelper.js:

```
import {ToastSeverity} from 'primevue/api';

export class toastService {
  constructor(toastInstanse, defaultLifeTime) {
    this.toastInstanse = toastInstanse
    this.defaultLifeTime = defaultLifeTime ? defaultLifeTime : "3000" 
  }
  displayInfo(title = 'Info', body = '', lifeTime = this.defaultLifeTime){
    this.toastInstanse.add({severity: ToastSeverity.INFO, summary: title, detail: body, life: lifeTime});
  }
}
```

In your component:

```
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast';
import { toastService } from "@/utilities/toastNotificationHelper.js";
const toastNotifications = new toastService(useToast())

onMounted(() => {
  toastNotifications.displayInfo()
});
```

**With a function**

In toastNotificationHelper.js:

```
import {ToastSeverity} from 'primevue/api';

const defaultLifeTime = 3000;

export function toastInfoNotification(toastInstanse, title = 'Info', body = '', lifeTime = defaultLifeTime) {
    toastInstanse.add({severity: ToastSeverity.INFO, summary: title, detail: body, life: lifeTime});
};
```

In your component:

```
import { toastInfoNotification } from "@/utilities/toastNotificationService.js";
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast';
const toast = useToast();

onMounted(() => {
  toastInfoNotification(toast)
});
```

Comment: Really good solution, I'll mark as correct as well, since it is a native one and doesn't export anything from main.ts.

Answer (score 12):

This solution works for me, but I'm not sure it's a good solution.

First: export app from main.ts

```
// main.ts
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from '@/App.vue';

import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import ToastService from 'primevue/toastservice';

export const app = createApp(App);

app.use(PrimeVue);
app.use(ToastService);

app.mount('#app')
```

Second: import app and use toast service with `app.config.globalProperties`

```
// myToastService.ts
import {ToastSeverity} from 'primevue/api';
import {app} from '@/main';

const lifeTime = 3000;

export function info(title: string = 'I am title', body: string = 'I am body'): void {
  app.config.globalProperties.$toast.add({severity: ToastSeverity.INFO, summary: title, detail: body, life: lifeTime});
};

export function error(title: string = 'I am title', body: string = 'I am body'): void {
  app.config.globalProperties.$toast.add({severity: ToastSeverity.ERROR, summary: title, detail: body, life: lifeTime});
};
```

Third: import myToastService in your component.

```
// myTestToastComponent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import {info, error} from '@/components/myToastService';

info();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see why this isn't a good approach. I did the same thing to add global filters in vue3. I'll try this approach and if it works, I'll upvote!! Thanks in advance for the answer, I'm confident it will solve my problem.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I'm upvoting your solution because it is with pure Vue and JS.
Why did you say it was not a good approach?

Comment: I think it's kind of weird to export the whole app and import it again in the App. But I have same idea with you that I don't want to use Pinia or Vuex to solve this problem.

Comment: At first when I was implementing your solution, I didn't see that you were exporting the 'app' const, and the I got an error. After exporting it I thought a bit weird as well, but at least it was a clean solution with no vuex, and no complexity at all. I'm gonna take a look if it is a bad practice to export the whole app.

Comment: It's slightly weird to export app just to import it elsewhere, but it's the best way to get access to global properties. The toast function can be further simplified by doing `app.$toast....`

Comment: Update: Instead of exporting all the app I just exported the app.config.globalProperties.$toast and imported it in my ToastService.ts.
This way I avoided exporting and importing all the vue app inside the app haha.
This one is still the best solution for me, since it is a native one.

Comment: I implemented this solution and it was working perfectly. Then i noticed that on the vite hot reloads it's showing bunch of errors, like: "[Vue warn]: App has already been mounted.
If you want to remount the same app, move your app creation logic into a factory. Sometimes app was crashing. Any ideas?

Comment: @dymek662 have you tried exporting only the app.config.globalProperties.$toast as I mentioned previously?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the following solution works for you:

Add a Toast in App.vue and add a watch that checks a message from the store

```
<template>
  <router-view />
  <Toast position="bottom-right" group="br" />
</template>
<script>
import { watch } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";
export default {
  setup() {
   const store = useStore();
   const toast = useToast();

    watch(
      () => store.getters.getErrorMessage,
       (message, prevMessage) => {
        console.log("error message", message);
        if (message) {
          toast.add({
            severity: "error",
            summary: "Error",
            detail: message,
            group: "br",
            life: 6000,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  },
};
</script>
```

Store

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
    state: { errorMessage: "" },
    mutations: {        
        setErrorMessage(state, payload) {
            state.errorMessage = payload;
        },
    },
    actions: {},
    modules: {},
    getters: {   
            getErrorMessage: (state) => state.errorMessage,
    },
});
```

then, in any other component just update the message

```
store.commit("setErrorMessage", error.message);
```

Comment: It is actually a good approach to solve my problem, but I actually didn't want to use Vuex for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

### No createApp export, can be used anywhere

Here's my solution without exporting `createApp`
It uses primevue's `toasteventbus`

`toasteventbus` doesn't come with built-in types

```
// env.d.ts
declare module 'primevue/toasteventbus' {
  import type { EventBus } from 'primevue/utils'
  export default {} as ReturnType<typeof EventBus>
}
```

```
// composables/toast.ts

import toasteventbus from 'primevue/toasteventbus'

export function info(summary: string, detail: string, life: number = 8000) {
  toasteventbus.emit('add', { severity: 'info', summary, detail, life })
}

export function warn(summary: string, detail: string, life: number = 8000) {
  toasteventbus.emit('add', { severity: 'warn', summary, detail, life })
}

export function success(summary: string, detail: string, life: number = 8000) {
  toasteventbus.emit('add', { severity: 'success', summary, detail, life })
}

export function error(summary: string, detail: string, life: number = 8000) {
  toasteventbus.emit('add', { severity: 'error', summary, detail, life })
}
```

## Usage

It works in vue and ts/js files

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as toast from '@/composables/toast'
toast.success('Yay', 'It works in Vue SFC')
</script>
```

```
import * as toast from '@/composables/toast'

fetch('...').then(() => {
   toast.success('Yay', 'It works in any file')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

After playing around with it for a while, I found a solution I believe to be elegant, though it uses Pinia. With this method, you can call toasts in helper functions as well, and reusing the functions are quite simplistic.

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";
import Toast from "primevue/toast";


createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(PrimeVue)
    .use(createPinia())
    .use(ToastService)
    .component("Toast", Toast)
    .mount("#app");
```

**interfaces.ts**

```
export interface Message {
    severity: string;
    summary: string;
    detail: string;
}
```

**useNotifications.ts**

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { Message } from "@interfaces";

interface State {
    info: Message;
    notify: Message;
    confirm: Message;
}

const useNotifications = defineStore({
    id: "notificationStore",
    // Might be better to only have one piece of state, but this is the solution I went with
    // info for basic notifs, notify for sticky notifs, confirm for notifs that need confirmation
    state: (): State => ({
        info: {
            severity: "",
            summary: "",
            detail: "",
        },
        notify: {
            severity: "",
            summary: "",
            detail: "",
        },
        confirm: {
            severity: "",
            summary: "",
            detail: "",
        },
    }),
});

export default useNotifications;
```

**App.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";
    import { useNotifications } from "@store";
    import { Message } from "@interfaces";

    const notificationStore = useNotifications();
    const toast = useToast();

    // Watches changes on notificationStore throughout the app
    notificationStore.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        // Checks which part of the state has been mutated, and updates that state based on those conditions
        // mutation.events.key will throw a TypeScript error, but it will still work (until build time where another solution should be found)
        const key = mutation.events.key;
        if (key === "info") {
            const { severity, summary, detail } = state.info;
            toast.add({ severity, summary, detail, life: 3000, group: "br" });
        } else if (key === "notify") {
            const { severity, summary, detail } = state.notify;
            toast.add({ severity, summary, detail, group: "br" });
        } else if (key === "confirm") {
            const { severity, summary, detail } = state.confirm;
            toast.add({ severity, summary, detail, group: "bc" });
        }
    });

    // Use provide to make Toast functionality easily injectable
    provide("toastConfirm", (args: Message) => {
        const { severity, summary, detail } = args;
        notificationStore.confirm = { severity, summary, detail };
    });
    provide("toastNotify", (args: Message) => {
        const { severity, summary, detail } = args;
        notificationStore.notify = { severity, summary, detail };
    });
    provide("toastInfo", (args: Message) => {
        const { severity, summary, detail } = args;
        notificationStore.info = { severity, summary, detail };
    });

    const denyToast = () => {
        toast.removeGroup("bc");
    };
    // Have not figured out how to make this function useable
    const acceptToast = () => {
        toast.removeGroup("bc");
    };
</script>

<template>
    <!-- This group will represent the toasts I do not wish to have to confirm -->
    <Toast position="bottom-right" group="br" />
    <!-- The 'confirmable' toast template is basically copy pasted from PrimeVue docs -->
    <!-- This Toast will appear in the bottom center -->
    <Toast position="bottom-center" group="bc">
        <template #message="slotProps">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <i class="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" />
                    <h4>{{ slotProps.message.summary }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ slotProps.message.detail }}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <Button class="p-button-danger" label="No" @click="denyToast" />
                        <Button class="p-button-success" label="Yes" @click="acceptToast" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </Toast>
</template>
```

**AnyChildComponent.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { inject } from "vue";
    import { Message } from "@interface";

    const notifyMe = inject("toastNotify", (args: Message) => {});

    const handleClick = () => {
        notifyMe({
            severity: "success",
            summary: "success!",
            detail: "this is from child component",
        });
    };
</script>

<template>
    <Button @click="handleClick" />
</template>
```

**exampleOfUsageInHelperFunction.ts**

```
import { useNotifications } from "@store";

// Database helper function
const send = async (channel: string, data?: Object) => {
    const notificationStore = useNotifications();
    if (data) data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

    // response will return something like: { message: "Query failed", error: error } or { message: "Query succeeded", success?: returnData }
    const response = await window.electron.ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data);
    if (response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
        notificationStore.notify = {
            severity: "danger",
            summary: "Error",
            detail: response.message,
        };
    } else {
        notificationStore.info = {
            severity: "success",
            summary: "Success",
            detail: response.message,
        };
        if (response.success) return response.success;
    }
};

export default send;
```

Comment: I liked your approach as well, but I'm not marking it as the one who best solved my problem because I found it a bit too complex and long.
Moreover, you had to use another lib (Pinia) and VueX, which I really didn't want to use it.

Comment: Take care about inserting too much logic in your app.vue ! Create a notif.vue file with all the logic and simply import it in the app.vue. Easier to test and maintain ! (But thank you for your work, it was great for my purpose ! :) )

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to handle toasts in a single location (`App.vue`) and then receive them via a message bus.

First set up a bus in `main.js`:

```
import mitt from 'mitt'
const toastBus = mitt()

const app = createApp(App)
// Provide the bus for injection for use by components
app.provide('toastBus', toastBus)

// Export the bus for use by 'non-component' scripts
export { toastBus }
```

Then inject the bus into App.vue, listen for events and generate toasts:

```
<template>
<div id="app"></div>
<Toast />
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast'

const toastBus = inject('toastBus')
const toast = useToast()

toastBus.on('*', (type, args) => {
  if (type === 'add') {
    toast.add(args)
  } else if (type === 'remove') {
    toast.remove(args)
  }
})
```

Then to send a toast from a component:

```
let toastBus = inject('toastBus')

toastBus.emit('add', { severity: 'success', summary: 'Test', detail: 'Test', life: 3000 })
```

Or from non-component code:

```
import { toastBus } from './main'

toastBus.emit('add', { severity: 'success', summary: 'Test', detail: 'Test', life: 3000 })
```

Comment: I like this answer as it is short and sweet, but need a little adjustment, please check below.

Comment: You are hosed if your non-component code is imported into your App.vue component. You run into a dependency issue then.

Answer (score 1):

for answer:[above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71680441/5687254) @match and for those who are struggling change App.vue to:

```
  <template>
       <div id="app"></div>
       <Toast />
  </template>
    
  <script>
    import { inject } from 'vue'
    import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast'
    
    export default {
       setup() {
          const toastBus = inject('toastBus')
          const toast = useToast()
    
          toastBus.on('*', (type, args) => {
          if (type === 'add') {
            toast.add(args)
          } else if (type === 'remove') {
            toast.remove(args)
          }
       })    
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example for anyone who needs to use toast in the *js* file**

```
 // App.vue

        <template>
            <Toast />
        </template>
        
        <script>
        import Toast from "primevue/toast";
        
        export default {
          components: {
            Toast: Toast,
          },
        </script>
```

- 

```
// store.js

        import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";
        
        export const StoreExample = defineStore("StoreExample", () => {
          const toast = useToast();
    
          const onActionGetProducts = async () => {
             return API_EXAMPLE.onApiGetProducts().then(() => {
    
               toast.add({
                  severity: "success",
                  summary: "Success Message",
                  detail: "Order submitted",
                  life: 3000,
               });
             });
          };
    
         return {
           onActionGetProducts,
         };
       });
```